# Assigning Names to Multiple client in Unix domain Socket

Tags: c, multithreading, unix-socket

so far everything have been working perfectly. Just the problem I've been having is that I can't think of a way of assigning or i would say giving names to the clients who are connect to the server so that other clients who know is wrote a message

server:

```
while (1) {
FD_ZERO(&read_set);
//FD_ZERO(&write_set);

FD_SET(fd, &read_set);
//FD_SET(fd, &write_set);

for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) { //at first this part will not excute
  FD_SET(clients[i], &read_set);
}

select(fd + num_clients + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);


if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_set)) {
  if ( (clients[num_clients++] = accept(fd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
    perror("accept error");
    continue;
  }
  printf("we got a connection!\n");
}


for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) {

  if (FD_ISSET(clients[i], &read_set)) {
    msg = read(clients[i], buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(msg > 0){
      int savedclnt = clients[i];
      printf("client %d says: %s\n", i, buf);

      for(int p=0;p<num_clients;p++)
      {
        if( clients[p]!= savedclnt){
          //write("from %d",clients[p]);
          //char msg2 = strcat(clients[i],msg);
          write(clients[p],buf,msg);
        }

      }
    }

  }

}
```

}

Comment: You are missing some code, but is this not what you are doing (naming your clients) with `if ( (clients[num_clients++] = accept(fd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {`

Comment: not really they are two different things.

Comment: Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming by "names" that you mean reliable ones (that provide UID and/or GID of the clients), then there are some ways...**

### Using Different Paths

You can use different file system paths with different permissions and owners for this. That way only certain users or groups can access some of the UNIX domain sockets and you can track who the client is based on who the client is running as. Here's a web page of info for this: https://troydhanson.github.io/network/Unix_domain_sockets.html

The technique essentially means providing a separate Unix domain socket per user or per group and using a mechanism that limits access to each socket to that user or group. The first part of this is just that: rather than having a single Unix domain socket bound to a file name, we use multiple sockets each bound to its own file. The second part of this is dealing with potentially differences in Unix socket implementations. An [online manual page for Unix sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) states (among other things) that:

> POSIX does not
>          make any statement about the effect of the permissions on a socket
>          file, and on some systems (e.g., older BSDs), the socket permissions
>          are ignored.  Portable programs should not rely on this feature for
>          security.

To deal with this, instead of using the permissions/ownership of the socket, the permissions and ownership of the socket's enclosing directory can be used instead.

Here's what the server code could look like then to implement this for a preselected and hardcoded set of two users: a user login of "jill" with a user ID of 1003 (and a group ID of 1003), and a user login of "bob" with a user ID of 1004 (and a group ID of 1004):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

struct user
{
    const char* name;
    uid_t uid;
    gid_t gid;
    int fd;
};

struct user users[] = {
    {"jill", 1003, 1003, -1},
    {"bob", 1004, 1004, -1},
};

static int nusers = 2;

static const char sockpath[] = "socket";

static void mk_user_dir(const struct user* u)
{
    if (mkdir(u->name, 0500) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
    {
        perror("mkdir");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (chown(u->name, u->uid, u->gid) == -1)
    {
        perror("chown");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static void bind_user_sock(const char* dir, const char* path, int sock)
{
    if (chdir(dir) == -1)
    {
        perror("chdir into userdir");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (unlink(path) == -1 && errno != ENOENT)
    {
        perror("unlink socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    assert(strlen(path) < sizeof(addr.sun_path));
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (chdir("..") == -1)
    {
        perror("chdir back into parent");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

struct session
{
    struct user* user;
    int fd;
};

#define MAX_SESSIONS 10

struct session sessions[MAX_SESSIONS];

static void setup_user(struct user* u)
{
    mk_user_dir(u);

    u->fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (u->fd == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bind_user_sock(u->name, sockpath, u->fd);

    if (listen(u->fd, 5) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "listening on %s/%s\n", u->name, sockpath);
}

int main()
{
    umask(077);

    int nsessions = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SESSIONS; i++)
    {
        sessions[i].user = NULL;
        sessions[i].fd = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nusers; i++)
    {
        setup_user(users + i);
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        int nfds = 0;
        fd_set readfds;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        for (int i = 0; i < nusers; i++)
        {
            FD_SET(users[i].fd, &readfds);
            if (nfds < users[i].fd)
                nfds = users[i].fd;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SESSIONS; i++)
        {
            if (sessions[i].fd != -1)
            {
                FD_SET(sessions[i].fd, &readfds);
                if (nfds < sessions[i].fd)
                    nfds = sessions[i].fd;
            }
        }

        nfds++;

        fprintf(stderr, "calling select for descriptors up to %d\n", nfds);
        if (select(nfds, &readfds, 0, 0, 0) == -1)
        {
            perror("select");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (nsessions > 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "checking for session activity for %d sessions\n", nsessions);
            int nclosed = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SESSIONS; i++)
            {
                if (sessions[i].fd != -1 && FD_ISSET(sessions[i].fd, &readfds))
                {
                    char buf[1024];

                    /* handle session activity (from user associated with session) */

                    int nread = read(sessions[i].fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
                    if (nread == -1)
                    {
                        perror("read");
                        if (errno != EBADF)
                        {
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                    }

                    if (nread > 0)
                    {
                        /* handle new session data */
                        fprintf(stderr, "read %d bytes from user %s\n", nread, users[i].name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* client closed session */
                        fprintf(stderr, "closing session for user %s\n", users[i].name);
                        close(sessions[i].fd);
                        sessions[i].fd = -1;
                        sessions[i].user = NULL;
                        nclosed++;
                    }
                }
            }
            nsessions -= nclosed;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "checking for new session requests for %d users\n", nusers);
        for (int i = 0; i < nusers; i++)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(users[i].fd, &readfds))
            {
                /* handle new session request from user */
                struct sockaddr_un addr;
                socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
                int fd = accept(users[i].fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen);
                if (fd == -1)
                {
                    perror("accept");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                fprintf(stderr, "accept: new session requested from user %s\n", users[i].name);

                int accepted = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SESSIONS; j++)
                {
                    if (sessions[j].fd == -1)
                    {
                        sessions[nsessions].fd = fd;
                        sessions[nsessions].user = users + i;
                        nsessions++;
                        accepted = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!accepted)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "rejected new session request from %s: out-of-sessions\n", users[i].name);
                    close(fd);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Using `getpeereid` (or `LOCAL_PEERCRED`)

While I have not used this myself, a simpler solution - seemingly available on some Unix systems - is to use the [`getpeerid` function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpeereid).

Comment: i will try to read through this to see if i will find solution to this problem.

Comment: Couldn't get anything useful from the link and am still stuck with this problem

Comment: @johnleonard onwuzuruigbo I've updated my answer to hopefully be a more thorough and better answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer again to include defining what I mean by "names" and also to add a much simpler though likely less portable mechanism.